# Scripts causing some web pages to cause sustained CPU load on Microsoft browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have noticed that some web pages, cause a long and sustained CPU utilization when visited using either Microsoft's Edge or IE browsers, but not using Chrome.   I seem to be observing this more and more.   What would cause this? [Title updated to reflect apparent cause.]

An example of a page doing this can be found at http://www.slashgear.com/cortana-syncs-notifications-between-windows-10-and-android-devices-19440717/

Using the Edge developer tools, seems edge is spending most of its time in scripting activity, but I'm not sure what would be causing it to keep up such activity for as long as it does.

Performance diagnostic trace at https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F13D953A30F77C70!187836&authkey=!AMDVNSYL_i_xUVM&ithint=file%2cdiagsession, can anyone provide guidance on reading this?

Comment: Note: I notice an involved script hosted on z.moatads.com   This domain seems have a bad reputation, and may be blocked entirely by extensions I've installed on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The cause seems to be bloated advertising scripts, which seem quite common these days on even mainstream sites.   As a workaround, I've tamed them by adding the following domains to Internet Explorer's Restricted zone.

- adsafeprotected.com
- doubleclick.net
- googlesyndication.com
- moatads.com
- serving-sys.com
- tabloola.com

Unfortunately the Edge browser doesn't seem to have this functionality.   Is there a better way to accomplish this sort of script abuse blocking?